# Assign values by matching two arrays

Tags: php

I feel really stupid right now since I can remember doing something like this. But now my head is empty and this really seems to look like a problem.

I have two arrays. First:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'name' => 'Blizzard',
    'slug' => 'blizzard',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'name' => 'Id Software',
    'slug' => 'id-software',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '3',
    'name' => 'Capcom',
    'slug' => 'capcom',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '4',
    'name' => 'Maxis',
    'slug' => 'maxis',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => '5',
    'name' => 'Electronic Arts',
    'slug' => 'electronic-arts',
  ),
)
```

And secound one:

```
array (
  0 => '3',
  1 => '4',
)
```

What I want to do is, take value from the **secound** array and match it with the value of the first one. How can I do this?

Comment: You mean you want `$array1[$array2[0]]`? Or match it to the 'id' of the one of the elements in array 1?

Comment: What do you mean by "match it with the value of the first one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "by value", I'm assuming you meant by `id` value, in which case, if you already know that the `id` value is one less than the key, you can do this:

```
foreach( $second as $id) {
    $key = $id - 1;
    $row = $first[ $key ];
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to loop / search for the specific `id`:

```
foreach( $second as $id) {
    foreach( $first as $row) {
         if( $row['id'] == $id) {
              echo $row['name']; break;
         }
    }        
}
```

However, another trick you can use to just get an array containing the elements you want is to use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter), like so:

```
$second = array( 3, 4);
$keep = array_filter( $first, function( $el) use( $second) { 
    return in_array( $el['id'], $second); 
});
```

Now `$keep` will contain an array of the two values you want, and you can loop over them accordingly.

Comment: Your secound solution works great. I can clearly remember doing something similar a couple of months ago, well... short mind ;) Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ( $secoundarray as $key => $value ) {
  $new_array[$key] = $firstarray[$value];
}
```